# Using StorybookJS in a component library package with React as peer dependency

Tags: reactjs, webpack, package.json, storybook

I am creating my own React component library. The `package.json` is using `react` and `react-dom` as peer dependencies because I only want to ship code for components only. This package will then be used in other React-based projects so I will provide React myself in those projects.

I've decided for adding StorybookJS in the package for two reasons

1. Help during development to preview my components
2. Create a static storybook site that I will host somewhere showcasing the components

My project structure:

```
package.json
src/
  components/ // contains components
  storybook/ // <-- not part of the package
  index.ts  // <-- this is entry point of the package
```

However this introduces a problem. Since StorybookJS requires `react` and `react-dom` to run, I would have to include them as dependencies of the library.

I will be using `webpack` to actually bundle only the component code so it can be distributed. Should I just use `externals` property in configuration to exclude `react` and `react-dom` from the bundle? I guess it would work but then the `package.json` would still list React as its dependencies (which I do not want).

What is the correct approach here?

Comment: Running into the same thing - did you ever get an answer?

Comment: No answer as you can see but I will provide one shortly here @PatrickDench

Answer (score 1):

I ended up putting `react` and `react-dom` into `peerDependencies` as that is correct approach in my opinion. Since that package file belongs to library itself (and not Storybook), it should correctly state its dependencies.

To avoid bundling React into my library bundle, I put it into `externals` webpack configuration like so:

```
  externals: {
    react: 'react',
    'react-dom': 'react-dom',
  },
```

This way, React or ReactDOM does not end up in the bundle. The library is React component library so it can't be used without React anyway and you should provide it.

The final step to make Storybook work, I added `prepare` script that installs peer dependencies when you install the package. That way React and ReactDOM are provided for Storybook application.

This is the prepare script in my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "prepare": "install-peers && npm run build"
}
```

I used [`install-peers` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/install-peers) to install React and ReactDOM. For newer version of NPM client, you will not need this package and [running `npm install` should install peer dependencies as well](https://github.blog/2021-02-02-npm-7-is-now-generally-available/#peer-dependencies).

Comment: Yep, this is basically what we ended up doing.  We started with lerna for installing all the deps.  But with storybook and some other deps we're working on migrating to npm@7.  Which has opened a whole other can of worms.

Comment: hello would you mind explaining a bit more your solution? I am using yarn and storybook 7.0.0-beta.13, which is inviting me to install react-dom and react as devDependencies (Starting in 7.0, react and react-dom are now required peer dependencies of Storybook).

Answer (score 1):

You can tell npm to automatically install the peers in `.npmrc`:

```json
auto-install-peers: true
```

I've expected a similar option for `.yarnrc.yml`...

[This alternative](https://github.com/nathanhleung/install-peerdeps) has been mentioed already.

Haven't tried it yet, but red through code and it looks good to me.

**Update:**

You might consider to not have peer dependencies (no nodeLinker) using Yarn PnP or PNPM workspaces (symlinks dependencies among packages while installing it only once in root .pnpm folder)

You might consider to use [meta](https://github.com/mateodelnorte/meta) and install dependencies via `meta exec` (uses `loop` internally.

I also thought about using a GitHub hook (husky) to add the peers to each package before commit/push (to get independent packages) but found a more elegant approach:

[You can add a GitHub workflow to split dependencies in the CI pipeline](https://github.com/danharrin/monorepo-split-github-action)

However best practices depend on project size and purpose. I want my packages standalone but while coding I prefer keeping it all together...

Comment: hello would you mind explaining a bit more your solution? I am using yarn and storybook 7.0.0-beta.13, which is inviting me to install react-dom and react as devDependencies (Starting in 7.0, react and react-dom are now required peer dependencies of Storybook).

Comment: yes. Actually there is no node_modules and duplicated packages using PNPM. Additionally or instead of you could work in a MonoRepo and a) install shared libraries using a own workspace and import from there (sounds logic, will find out by tomorrow I guess) or b) just install them in the root of the Monorepo until you want a standalone package (then finally you have to install the dependencies, to make it work, it's just a dependency

Comment: @user2929613 you might be interested in my update (added to my original answer)